# predict function return less samples

Tags: r, r-caret, predict

I train the model using train function in caret R package. When I test the model in my test data which has 45 samples, the predict function only return the label of the classes for only 43 samples. I attached the rda data which contain the test data and my model. I appreciate your help.
[test_data+model](http://fadhl-alakwa.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/6/4/5364958/modelanddata.rda)

Here is the code I use:

```
dim( test_data[,!(colnames(test_data) %in% c('lable')) ])
```

45  179

```
dim(predict(mod, test_data[,!(colnames(test_data) %in% c('lable')) ],type="prob"))
```

43  2

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missing data in your data frame:

```
> pdata = data1[,!(colnames(data1) %in% c('lable')) ]
```

`pdata` has 45 rows, but:

```
> ok = complete.cases(pdata)
> sum(ok)
[1] 43
```

only 43 have complete data.

Which rows have missing data?

```
> rownames(pdata[!ok,])
[1] "GSM1388233" "GSM1388235"
```

No warning is given because the documentation says:

```
 ## S3 method for class 'train'
 predict(object, newdata = NULL, type = "raw",
   na.action = na.omit, ...)
```

which is saying to omit any rows with missing data - silently.